# Non-recurring, Randomized, 2D Char Array That Contains Alphabet For C++ Beginner

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix

Assignment wants from us to create a matrix 5x10 containing English letters randomly and non-recurringly. But since there are 52 letters and 50 rooms in the matrix I had to put away to of them. But if I can randomly generate them there still will me two letter missing but not the same ones.

my code is like this so far;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime> //for srand (number randomize)

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(time(0)); // generates random number 

    const int ROWS = 5; //declaration of rows

    const int COLUMNS = 10; //declaration of columns

    //writing content of the matrix

    //I took out two letter (v and V) because matrix limit was 50 but all letters were 52

    char harf[ROWS][COLUMNS] = {
                     {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'},
                     {'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T'},
                     {'U', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'},
                     {'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o'},
                     {'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'}
    };


    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)

    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLUMNS; ++j)

        {
            //generates a random index number

            int index1 = rand() % 5; //random numbers 0 to 5

            int index2 = rand() % 10; //random numbers 0 to 10


            //swaps harf [i][j] with harf [index1][index2] for it won't be repating itself

            char temp = harf[i][j];

            harf[i][j] = harf[index1][index2];

            harf[index1][index2] = temp;
        }
    }

    //printing header and random order matrix

    cout << "Random and nonrecurring matrix" << endl << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; ++i)

    {

        for (int j = 0; j < COLUMNS; ++j)

            cout << harf[i][j] << "     ";

        cout << endl << endl;

    }
```

I tried to make this way;

> char harf[ROWS][COLUMNS];
>
> for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
>
> {     for (int j = 0; j < COLUMNS; ++j)
>
> {
>
> ```
>   harf[i][j] = rand() % 25 + 65 && rand() % 25 + 97;      } }
> ```

I also tried the same thing with  " || " but does not seem to work.

Since this is an assignment I can not use anything more advanced than this kind of expressions. Can someone please tell me how to put the English alphabet into that matrix?

Comment: Start with a list of all uppercase and lowercase letters in a separate, one dimensional array. Remove two at random. Then, swap each element in that array with a random element selected from anywhere within the array. (This is "shuffle" randomization known to players of card games and MP3 files.) _Then_ put the results into your 2D array,

Comment: With the exception of removing two letters at random, your attempt seems to be doing pretty much what I said. What's wrong with your approach?

Comment: I have to use a 2d array and I have to use only 1 according to the assignment. I made something like this :

` for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)

 {
  for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j)

  {
   
   harf[i][j] = rand() % 25 + 'A';

  }
 }

 for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)

 {
  for (int j = 5; j < 10; ++j)

  {
   
   harf[i][j] = rand() % 25 + 'a';

  }
 } `

but it is repeating characters. @TimRandall @Mpops

Comment: Btw nothing is wrong except mine is missing V and v all the time but it should be randomly like everytime 2 letters will be missing but different. But I can not create two separate matrix or other 1d arrays.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create array of length 52.
2. Fill this array with the letters of the alphabet, in order if you want.
   `[abcde.....XYZ]`
3. Shuffle the entire array. 
   `[dPYka....slqEr]`
4. Remove the last two characters in the array.
   `[dPYka...slq]`
5. Now, to access your random letters, simply read either the first or last character in the array and remove it each time you read one.
   `[dPYka...slq]` --> `[dPYka...sl]` (read a 'q')
6. Fill your 2 dimensional array by accessing one letter at a time from this array, making sure to remove letters as you go.

If you do it this way, the random letters removed will be purely random (ha*) and the final 5x10 matrix will also be purely random (ha*).

*let's not get into the properties of truly random number generators.

Comment: No need in steps 4,5,6 to remove letters. just walk through the first 50 array elements and enter them sequentially in the 5x10 matrix

Comment: I am only allowed to create one matrix (I know it is dumb). but thanks for your answer.